# Python Check if item in different set, union them

Tags: python, list, set

Suppose `L = [{'C', 'T'}, {'L'}, {'M'}]`

let `c1 = 'C' and c2 = 'M'`

I want to union if c1 and c2 are in different sets.

How would I check that 'C' is in a different set than 'M' so that I can union it efficiently. I am trying to avoid multiple loops. (If c1 and c2 are in same set then do nothing)

For this example the output would be: `[{'C', 'T', 'M'}, {'L'}]`

Comment: What if there are multiple sets that contain "C" or "M"? For example, what would the expected output for `L = [{'C'}, {'C'}, {'M'}]` be?

Comment: There is a restriction that there are no repeating Chars. So 'C' will never appear twice.

Comment: Do you consider the `in` keyword to be a loop?

Comment: Does it matter which one of the two sets is removed from the list when they're merged?

Comment: What should happen if one letter is not found? What should happen if both letters are in the same set?

Comment: Your question is not quite clear, as the above comments show. Do you want your result list's first element to be the union of all sets in the list that contain either `c1` or `c2`, and you want the other elements to be the sets that contain neither, in the order they appear in the first list? This is if `c1` and `c2` are not in the same set--if they are, just return the first list? If this is not what you mean, what do you mean?

Answer (score 2):

The first step is to find the two sets that contain "C" and "M". Here's a solution that uses a generator expression to do so:

```
try:
    i1 = next(i for i, values in enumerate(L) if 'C' in values)
    i2 = next(i for i, values in enumerate(L) if 'M' in values)
except StopIteration:  # "C" or "M" wasn't found
    pass
else:    
    if i1 != i2:
        set1 = L[i1]
        set1.update(L.pop(i2))
```

This is in my opinion a good and readable solution, but if you *really* want to avoid looping over the data twice, you can merge the two generator expressions into a single loop:

```
i1 = i2 = None
for i, values in enumerate(L):
    if 'C' in values:
        i1 = i

    if 'M' in values:
        i2 = i

    if i1 is not None and i2 is not None:
        if i1 != i2:
            set1 = L[i1]
            set1.update(L.pop(i2))
        break
```

Both solutions modify `L` in-place. They do not create a new list.

Comment: The first one looks nice. I'm not sure if `'C'` and `'M'` are always present in `L`.

Comment: @EricDuminil Good point. I've added exception handling for when "C" or "M" aren't present in any of the sets. It now silently does nothing in that case.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly, this pretty straight forward function should do the trick. Uses one loop.

```
>>> def merge(sets, c1, c2):
...     merged = set()
...     other = [merged]
...     for s in sets:
...         if c1 in s or c2 in s:
...             merged.update(s)
...         else:
...             other.append(s)
...     return other
... 
>>> L = [{'C', 'T'}, {'L'}, {'M'}]
>>> c1 = 'C'
>>> c2 = 'M'
>>> 
>>> merge(L, c1, c2)
[set(['C', 'M', 'T']), set(['L'])]
```

I did not use the fact that each letter can appear only once since this would result in such a minor optimization (set membership test runs in O(1)) that I don't see the point in sacrificing readbility here.